# AWS CloudFront Domain name ownership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, domain-name

Is it possible to transfer the ownership of an existing CloudFront domain name to another AWS account?

the domain name looks like this `dXXXXXXXXXrfut.cloudfront.net`

I want this because this domain name has been used on some 3rd parties.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe it is possible to transfer a CloudFront distribution to another user.

> By cloudfront generated domain name, do you mean CloudFront Distribution name?
> If yes, unfortunately, you cannot move it. It’s specific to a particular account and cannot be moved.

— [anupm@AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238553)

Comment: L it's not under Route 53, Its a CloudFront Domain Name, dXXXXXXXXXrfut.cloudfront.net where CloudFront will generate it automatically for you

Comment: Oh, I see.  No, unfortunately I do not believe it is possible to transfer a CloudFront distribution to another user.  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238553

Comment: @AnthonyL please edit your answer to reflect your current understanding of the question.   It is correct that these names cannot be transferred.